# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token true

Tags: javascript, django

```
WHETHER_DJANGO_USER_IS_AUTH = "{{user.is_authenticated|yesno:"true, false"}}";
```

This code causes an error
I have tried try {} catch but it doesn't work for me.

> It says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token true

thx, everyone. I didn't think about the quote.

Comment: well you have nested quotes so you got a syntax error

Comment: On the yesno property, use single quotes.

Comment: I love you, thx, you made my day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use diferent quotes (single / double) inside and outside:

```
WHETHER_DJANGO_USER_IS_AUTH = '{{user.is_authenticated|yesno:"true, false"}}';
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the quotes, using the same quotes inside the string is causing the issue:

```
WHETHER_DJANGO_USER_IS_AUTH = "{{user.is_authenticated|yesno:'true, false'}}";
```

Comment: I think is more secure to not change the quotes inside the string (your 2nd option doesn't do it, but your first does). Maybe there is some parsing elsewhere which is expecting double quotes.

Comment: @raul.vila I agree, updated my answer. Thank for your input!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing somehing, now I only see the one with single quotes inside the string Ó_ò